# hibernate annotatedClasses in external file

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using spring + hibernate in my application.
I need to map the entities that are annoted by hibernate annotations.
I have this configuartion.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.repositoryComment.Model1</value>
            <value>com.example.repositoryControlUpload.Model2</value>
            <value>com.example.repositoryCycleTicketSummary.Model3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

I'd like that the entities configuration stay in another file.
Exemplo:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
           filesThatContainsModels
        </list>
    </property>
```

This classes (Model1, Model2, Model3) are annoted by hibernate.
I don't use packagesToScan, because my warmup need to be fast.

There is way for configuration only the class that annoted, but not using packagesToScan?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option at build-time would be to take advantage of annotation processing.

Basically a custom annotation processor will scan your source files at build time and generate a list of all files found to be annotated with `@Entity`.  It takes this list of classes along with an external property file that describes your static `SessionFactory` configuration and it generates your spring XML file as `applicationContext-persistence.xml`.

You then just make sure your main `applicationContext.xml` imports that file for runtime.

Another alternative would actually to use the `packagesToScan` property.  But rather than do what a lot of developers do and point it to the root package of your application, provide the property with a more restrictive list of packages that represent exactly where it should look, helping it avoid inspecting unnecessary classes.  For example:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <array>
    <value>com.company.application.feature1.persistence</value>
    <value>com.company.application.feature2.persistence</value>
    ...
  </array>
</property>
```

But I honestly think you're over optimizing.  If you have this type of bootstrap performance issues, there has to be something else going wrong here to give you cause for concern.

I have worked on a monolithic application with tens of thousands of class files where the scan pointed to the package root of the application and it didn't take any more than a few seconds to bootstrap the Hibernate persistence classes.

Comment: Hi @Naros, I have few class to scan, the problem is I have I time to bootstrap, one minute, so I have optimize each part of code that I can.
So, I'll analyze what you said, because, I really have few classes in my package and the class are in them same package
Thanks!!

Comment: One thing to make sure is that you aren't using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.  The schema comparison process can consume a lot of time in an application with lots of entities, so make sure to avoid that too.